# Laravel passing URL into a controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I need to pass a URL into a controller like so:

```
Route::get('vote/scraper?s={url}', 'VoteController@getUrlData');
```

But when I pass a url as such:

```
mysite.com/vote/scraper?s=http://www.example.com/fastrack-wayfarer-sunglasses/p/itmdx7z4hgjgp5st
```

Laravel thinks the other slashes in the URL as different views and throws NotFoundHttpException.

How do I do this ?

Comment: As some of the answers suggest. URLencode it first. You can do it with JS `encodeURIComponent('url')` this spits out `http%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%2ffastrack-wayfarer-sunglasses%2fp%2fitmdx7z4hgjgp5st` which you can `urldecode` serverside.

Comment: You probably meant `urlencode`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove query from route:

`Route::get('vote/scraper', 'VoteController@getUrlData');`

And try to get url from **Input::get()** like

```
$url = Input::get('url');
```

PS: Encoding URL in query is a good and recommended practice.

Answer (score 1):

This works !

`Route::get('add/{encoded_url}', function($encoded_url)
{
    return 'The URL is: '.rawurldecode($encoded_url);
})->where('encoded_url', '.*');`

Answer (score 1):

Transforming your code `mysite.com/vote/scraper?s=http://www.example.com/fastrack-wayfarer-sunglasses/p/itmdx7z4hgjgp5st` should be `mysite.com/vote/scraper?s=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ffastrack-wayfarer-sunglasses%2Fp%2Fitmdx7z4hgjgp5st`

You can get the encoded url with `urlencode` in php or `encodeURIComponent` in javascript (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Then, your route should be `Route::get('vote/scraper', 'VoteController@getUrlData');`

Lastly, in `getUrlData` use `$url = \Input::get('s');`

Or in Laravel 5.1

```
public function getUrlData(Request $request)
{
    $url = $request->input('s');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your URL with `urlencode()`.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php